# When a route gets a bad parameter, why do route links with other parameters get an "active" class?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an Ember site with a navigation bar that has multiple links to the same route but with different parameters, like this:

```
{{link-to '1' 'foo' 1}}
{{link-to '2' 'foo' 2}}
```

When I click on a link, it goes to the right page, and the link gets an `active` class, as expected.

However, when I enter a URL with a *bad* parameter for the same route (e.g. `/foo/bar`), it goes to my `error` route as expected, but it adds an `active` class to all `foo` links. I would expect that *none* of these `foo` links would appear active.

---

I can produce this behaviour with a very simple `ember-cli` app. All I have to do is run `ember new foobar` and add/edit a few files as shown below:

```
/* app/router.js */

import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('foo', {path: 'foo/:foo_id'});
});

export default Router;


/* app/routes/foo.js */

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    if (params.foo_id !== '1' && params.foo_id !== '2') {
      throw 'error';
    }
  }
});


/* app/routes/error.js */

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});


/* app/templates/application.hbs */

{{link-to '1' 'foo' 1}}
{{link-to '2' 'foo' 2}}
```

Then, when I run `ember s` and go to `http://localhost:4200/foo/bar` in my browser, all the links have the `active` class.

---

Is this an Ember bug, or am I doing something wrong, or is this the way Ember is designed to work? In any case, how can I prevent Ember from adding an `active` class to `foo` links when the user goes to a bad `foo` URL?

Comment: `foo` means active on all foo + children routes, it seems you want `foo.index`

Comment: @PatsyIssa: If I understand correctly, then that's not true: clicking the "1" link only makes *that* link active (not both of them). Even if I create an `index` child route of `foo` like this and link there instead, the problem still occurs:

```this.route('foo', function() {
    this.route('index', {path: ':foo_id'});
  });```

Comment: ur path for index needs to be path: 'index/foo_id'. The purpose of active is to show that these active links refer to the current chain of routes. so if current route is abc/xyz/def then the below links would be active: abc, abc/xyz and abc/xyz/def

Comment: A link being select as active has got nothing to do with bad parameters, both in ember and even logically

Comment: @wallop: Neither `index/foo_id` nor `index/:foo_id` solve the problem. I understand that a current `abc.xyz.def` route should make an `abc.xyz` link active – the problem is that going to `/abc/xyz/def/ghi` (i.e. passing the `ghi` parameter to the `abc.xyz.def` route) makes a `/abc/xyz/def/jkl` link active when `ghi` is a parameter that causes an error in the `model` function of the Ember route (whereas going to `/abc/xyz/def/jkl` does *not* make a `/abc/xyz/def/mno` link active when the `jkl` parameter does not cause an error).